# Undocumented WinAPI : LoadLibrary16 and GetProcAddress16

Tags: c++, winapi

```
typedef void (WINAPI *voidfunc)(void);
typedef HMODULE (WINAPI *strfunc1)(char*);
typedef HMODULE (WINAPI *strfunc2)(void*,char*);
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    HMODULE kernel=GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll");
    if(!kernel)return 1;
    strfunc1 LoadLibrary16=(strfunc1)GetProcAddress(kernel,"LoadLibrary16");
    if(!LoadLibrary16){ 
        MessageBoxA(0,"LoadLibrary16 is not imported","err",0);
        return 1;
    }
    HMODULE user=LoadLibrary16("user.exe");
    if(!user){  
        MessageBoxA(0,"user.exe is not loaded","err",0);
        return 1;
    }
    strfunc2 GetProcAddress16=(strfunc2)GetProcAddress(kernel,"GetProcAddress16");
    if(!GetProcAddress16){  
        MessageBoxA(0,"GetProcAddress16 is not imported","err",0);
        return 1;
    }
    voidfunc enable=(voidfunc)GetProcAddress16(user,"EnableOemLayer");
    voidfunc disable=(voidfunc)GetProcAddress16(user,"DisableOemLayer");
    if(!(enable&&disable))return 1;
    disable();
    Sleep(5000);
    enable();

    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work.

PS my os is Win 7.

PPS Firstly i tryed simply LoadLibraryA, got error, read a bit and understood i need 16-bit undocumented functions.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't enough information to give you any meaningful help.

Comment: Unable to import 16-bit functions.
Win7 x86.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  I'm not sure if the APIs you're trying to use even exist, but it's likely there's a simpler way to achieve your goal

Comment: "Undocumented" is "non-existing" here.  16-bit programs run in the ntvmd.exe process, it emulates a 16-bit runtime environment.  Using 32-bit apis in a 16-bit process can't work, appending "16" doesn't help.

Comment: @HansPassant: One of several ways to call 32-bit APIs from a 16-bit process: http://www.tenermerx.com/owlhow/items/miscellaneous/thunk/index.html

Comment: @arx - wrong way around.  This is about a 32-bit process trying to run 16-bit code.  I think...

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid there is NO 16bit functions in kernel32.dll.
The functions that can be found are

```
LoadLibraryA
LoadLibraryExA
LoadLibraryExW
LoadLibraryW
```

A useful tool is dependency, and you can find it from
    http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 1):

LoadLibrary16 and GetProcAddress16 do NOT exist in kernel32.dll

See [image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Only kernel32.dll on Windows 95/98/ME have LoadLibrary16 and GetProcAddress16 and they are not exported by name.